# How to access data received from an api outside of service block in same controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

---

I am using Angular 1.7.8, and I have a controller that calls a service that receive data from an API, the problem is that, I cannot access the data outside of service block in same controller.

```
app.controller('AppController', function ($scope, DataService) {

    let fieldProperties = {};

    $scope.findInData = function (value) {
        DataService.getData().then(function (response) {
            $scope.result = response.data;
            if (response.data !== undefined) {
                for (let idx in $scope.result) {
                    if ($scope.result.hasOwnProperty(idx)) {
                        if (value === $scope.result[idx].fieldname) {
                            fieldProperties = {
                                'fieldName': $scope.result[idx].fieldname,
                                'preferredFieldName': $scope.result[idx].preferredfieldname,
                                'fieldValue': $scope.result[idx].fieldvalue,
                                'isEditable': $scope.result[idx].editable,
                                'isMandatory': $scope.result[idx].mandatory,
                                'isAutoClear': $scope.result[idx].autoclear
                            };
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.resultFieldProperties = fieldProperties;
});
```

Also I want to mention that, putting $scope on fieldProperties directly is not a solution for me, because I need to send this result to directive scope, fieldProperties object as scope as well is undefined outside of service block, any other suggestions please !?

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but if you put the `$scope.resultFieldProperties = {'fieldName': $scope.result[idx].fieldname, ...}`, will it work with you? because `resultFieldProperties` will always be undefined as the `getData()` is async and needs time to be completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the result to your variable by calling the function

```
$scope.findInData = function (value) {
    DataService.getData().then(function (response) {
        $scope.result = response.data;
        if (response.data !== undefined) {
            for (let idx in $scope.result) {
                if ($scope.result.hasOwnProperty(idx)) {
                    if (value === $scope.result[idx].fieldname) {
                        fieldProperties = {
                            'fieldName': $scope.result[idx].fieldname,
                            'preferredFieldName': $scope.result[idx].preferredfieldname,
                            'fieldValue': $scope.result[idx].fieldvalue,
                            'isEditable': $scope.result[idx].editable,
                            'isMandatory': $scope.result[idx].mandatory,
                            'isAutoClear': $scope.result[idx].autoclear
                        };
                        return fieldProperties;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
};

$scope.resultFieldProperties = $scope.findInData('<some_value>');
```

Otherwise, you need to have a callback function as argument and that can return data to you onComplete.

Answer (score 1):

You can store data in the variable. Like this

```
  $scope.storedresult=$scope.findInData('value');
```

you can acess storedresult in whole of your controller.